# Store vector result from a loop into matrix when the dimension in unkown in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I want to store the vector result from a loop into a matrix, but I do not know the number of rows. For example, the following code will illustrate what I want to do:

```
result_final <- c()
for (i in 1:5){
   n <- sample(1:5,1) #get the number of rows for this iteration
   result_this_time <- matrix(0,n,3) #generate a matrix with row number 
                                     #are unknown before running the iteration
   #combine all the results from each iteration together 
   if (i == 1) result_final <- result_this_time
       else result_final <- rbind(result_final,result_this_time)
    }
result_final
```

The above code works for me. The problem is that it is a little complex. As you can see, when I use `c()` to generate the new vector, I do not have to indicate the length of vector. The code `test1 <- c();test1[3]<-1` will not report any error, but the code`test2 <- matrix();test2[3,3]<-1` will report an error as refer to wrong subscript.  So I wonder is there anyway that I can create a "matrix" that I do not have to explicitly indicate the rows of matrix(just like to create a vector using `c()`) in order to get rid of `if` statement.

Comment: Could you explain a little  bit more of what you're trying to accomplish? The error in `test2 <- matrix();test2[3,3]<-1` is that matrix() creates a 1x1 matrix with NA at [1, 1]. What is the complex part that you're describing, or trying to get rid of? And what is test1? A placeholder for "result_this_time"?

Comment: I want to get rid of `if statement` . When you want to store your result into a vector, you can just use `c()` to create the new vector without knowing the dimension. It is really convenient when you do not know the length of vector you need. But for matrix, it does not work. If you want to store your result which is a vector as a row a matrix, you have to know the number of rows before. But in the situation of my example, you do not know how many rows you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the answer above, create a list to store your results and then bind them together.

```
result_list <- list()
for(i in 1:5){
  n <- sample(1:5, 1)
  result_list[[i]] <- matrix(0, n, 3)
}
result_final <- do.call(rbind, result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do using `lapply()`. The outer `lapply()` controls the overall repetition while the inner `lapply()` does the number of rows assigned by `n`. `do.call()` is used to simplify and bind (`rbind()`) the elements. A comparison is made to the original code below.

```
set.seed(1237)
# outer loop controls overall repetition
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:5, function(x) {
  n <- sample(1:5, 1)
  # inner loop control individual rows by n
  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:n, function(y) rbind(rep(0, 3))))
}))
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0
[7,]    0    0    0
[8,]    0    0    0
[9,]    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0

set.seed(1237)
result_final <- c()
for (i in 1:5){
  n <- sample(1:5,1) #get the number of rows for this iteration
  result_this_time <- matrix(0,n,3) #generate a matrix with row number 
  #are unknown before running the iteration
  #combine all the results from each iteration together 
  if (i == 1) result_final <- result_this_time
  else result_final <- rbind(result_final,result_this_time)
}
result_final
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0
[7,]    0    0    0
[8,]    0    0    0
[9,]    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0
```